# Migrated DB from 12c to 19c with IMPDP failed

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, impdp, oracle-19c

I have migrated a DB from 12c to 19c with `IMPDP` and `EXPDP`. While importing I have seen some errors. Below is an extract of the errors.

### Errors During Import

> ```
> Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
>
> Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/STATISTICS/MARKER
>
> VM247_RCDB_121GA.PK_TXI : sqlerrm = ORA-20000: Unable to set values for index PK
> _TXI: does not exist or insufficient privileges
>
> VM247_RCDB_121GA.PK_ARRE : sqlerrm = ORA-20000: Unable to set values for index P
> K_ARRE: does not exist or insufficient privileges
>
> VM247_RCDB_121GA.PK_ARA : sqlerrm = ORA-20000: Unable to set values for index PK
> _ARA: does not exist or insufficient privileges
>
> VM247_RCDB_121GA.SYS_C0034921 : sqlerrm = ORA-20000: Unable to set values for in
> dex SYS_C0034921: does not exist or insufficient privileges
>
> VM247_RCDB_121GA.PK_TXA : sqlerrm = ORA-20000: Unable to set values for index PK
> _TXA: does not exist or insufficient privileges
>
> Importing statistics failed for 20 object(s);
>
> Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/MATERIALIZED_VIEW
> Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01" completed with 22 error(s) at Wed Aug 7 08:2
> 8:32 2019 elapsed 0 00:05:25
> ```

The utilities are: `expdp` from 12c and `impdp` from 19c

### Commands Issued

On the 12c instance i exported using:

```
expdp system/admin@orcl schemas=VM247_RCDB_121GA directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR  
dumpfile=VM247_RCDB_121V10.dmp logfile=VM247_RCDB_121V10.log
```

...and imported on the 19c instance with:

```
impdp system/admin@orcl19c schemas=VM247_RCDB_121GA directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR 
dumpfile=VM247_RCDB_121V10.DMP logfile=VM247_RCDB_121V10_imp.log
```

Comment: Is the target schema useable, looks like it only misses the statistics. You might be able to just re-Analyse them.

Answer (score 1):

**2. Import excluding statistics in new system - Oracle 19c:**

```
$ impdp user/password@vcas exclude=statistics dumpfile=dump_file_name.dmp logfile=log_file_name.log  schemas=SCHEMA01, SCHEMA02, SCHEMA03, CHEMA04, SCHEMA05

Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully completed at Wed Apr 7 16:42:59 2021 elapsed 0 00:01:01
```

*** exclude=statistics

**2. Then, Gather table statistics for each schema manually, Oracle 19c:**

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL> EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_schema_stats(ownname =>'SCHEMA01', estimate_percent => 100);
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_schema_stats(ownname =>'SCHEMA02', estimate_percent => 100);
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_schema_stats(ownname =>'SCHEMA03', estimate_percent => 100);
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_schema_stats(ownname =>'SCHEMA04', estimate_percent => 100);
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_schema_stats(ownname =>'SCHEMA05', estimate_percent => 100);
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

SQL> exit;

**3. DONE!**

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem (bug 26380126). The workaround is to exclude statistics, and the re-gather in the target database. Or export using `DBMS_STATS`.

Actually, Oracle recommends that you never export the statistics with datapump. Use one of the above two mentioned methods instead.